# SQL concatenation only for selected condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to concatenate 'Local' with name only for Indian employee and other country employee name should be direct pull.

```
Select concat('Local' , Emp_Name) where country = 'India'


Aaaa India LocalAaaa
Bbbb Australia Bbbb
Cccc England Cccc
Dddd India LocalDddd
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Also: your select statement is invalid (the `from` clause is missing).

Comment: Select concat('Local' , Emp_Name) where country = 'India' from Employee


Aaaa India LocalAaaa
Bbbb Australia Bbbb
Cccc England Cccc
Dddd India LocalDddd

Comment: "SQL Developer" is not a DBMS - it is a SQL client application. But I guess it's safe to assume that you are using the Oracle DBMS in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a `case`:

```
select (case when country = 'India' then concat('Local', Emp_name) else Emp_Name end)
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this would be to do a union of the Indian employees, and all other employees:

```
    Select concat('Local' , Emp_Name) as 'Emp_name' 
    from employees 
    where country = 'India' 

    Union

    Select Emp_name 
    from employees 
    where country <> 'India'
```